# Issues regarding comments in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, comments

When I press `Ctrl + /` to start a comment line it starts at the beginning of the line like this

[image]

But I want to start the comment line after a tab space after clicking `Ctrl + /`. I want to have like this

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in eclipse settings?

Comment: I imagine you'll need to set it up in the code formatter, or maybe in the code template.

Comment: About which editor you are talking? Java?

Comment: Yup Java in Eclipse